# How to access and use the value of dictionary inside for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have dictionary with list of values i create before initiating a function. How to access the value of dictionary and print the values.

```html
data = {'A': 10, 'B': 20}
one = ['one','two']


def myfunction(a,b):
    print(a,b)

for x in one:

    filename = x
    for value in data.values():
        myfunction(x,value)
```

This print the different filename but i get value twice

So expected output is

```
one 10                                                                                                                                                                                                      
one 20                                                                                                                                                                                                      
two 10                                                                                                                                                                                                      
two 20
```

but expected output is

```
one 10                                                                                                                                                                                                      
two 20
```

Comment: What is `key` supposed to be?  It's not assigned any value in the code you posted.

Comment: @jasonharper key should be A and B

Comment: Please provide a [MRE]

Comment: Pay attention to indentation. You use 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 spaces on different lines of code. Use [4 spaces per indentation level](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation).

Comment: @pho sorry my bad, i have edited the code

Comment: @jarmod sorry i have edited the code that could be reasily reproducible.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this as asked, but did you perhaps want to look up something in the dictionary, rather than iterating over every value? Replace that loop with a simple lookup like value = data.get(filename, 'Default Value'). There has to be some reason (within the dict or computed key) why "one" gets associated with A and "two" with B, and you have not done that.

Comment: @KennyOstrom yeah sorry my bad i found my solution and posted as anser.

Comment: @jarmod - you don't have to use 4 spaces, you just have to use a consistent number of spaces. And even then that consistency only applies to the block the code resides in. For instance I could use 1 space for every method in a class, then 2 spaces inside the first method, 3 spaces inside the 2nd method, etc..

Comment: @OysterShucker sure, you could use 100 spaces in one indentation and 47 in the next, if you like. But you shouldn't.

Comment: @jarmod - you shouldn't use varying spaces because it makes the structure confusing but, saying it should be exactly 4 is an opinion. 2 spaces is also conventional. And honestly 1 space is all it takes.

Comment: I suggest you research how Python dictionaries are constructed and used. I recommend: https://docs.python.org/3.12/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: okay thanks @Codist

Comment: @OysterShucker 4 spaces is not just one individual's opinion on StackOverflow - it's the recommendation of PEP 8: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone but i think i got an answer using index

```
data = {'A': 10, 'B': 20}
one = ['one','two']


def myfunction(a,b):
    print(a,b)
    
mylist = list(data.value())    
count = 0
for x in one:

    filename = x
    myfunction(filename,mylist[count])
    count = count + 1
```

and it works.

Comment: @KennyOstrom yes kenny for my requirments, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your second for-loop, you can loop through both the key and the values of the dictionary:

```
for key, values in data.values(): 
    my_function(x, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over two things, but in separate loops, so of course you get every combination.

You wanted to combine them one-to-one, in order. "zip" is the Python builtin function for that. Imagine zip putting two iterables together much like a zipper works on clothing.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

```
data = {'A': 10, 'B': 20}
one = ['one','two']

for filename, value in zip(one, data.values()):
    print(filename, value)
```

> one 10
> two 20

We're completely ignoring why there's a dict in the first place, which really threw me off. It's also weird that there are exactly as many files in your directory as values in the dictionary -- maybe you want itertools.cycle, but I can't speculate on that as the requirements are ... unclear in the question.